# Can we use Column Range for Comparison in Google Spreadsheets Query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

Suppose I have a table with 3 columns in a Google Spreadsheets sheet. Col1 is a name and Col2 and Col3 are numbers. Can we use a column range for number comparison such as in the example below? (what I've written below obviously doesn't work)

`select * where Col1='John' AND Col2 to Col3 > 0`

Is there a way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Query Language hasn't a `to` operator.

Instead of `Col2 to Col3 > 0` try `Col2 > 0 AND Col3 > 0`

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: Thank you Ruben. I'm actually going through the reference now. The issue with my case is that I have a lot of columns I need to compare > 40. It would just be a drag to write all of them Col2 > 0 AND Col3 > 0 AND ... AND ... AND ... Col51 > 0 ...

I was looking for a way to specify a range instead of individual columns.

Comment: Probably no way around it though. I'll just mark this as the answer. Thank you!